# MyViewController XIB template

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I've got a helper class with a XIB that I'd like to re-use.

Here's what I'd like to be able to do:

1. write generic code in MyGenericController.h/.m/.xib
2. subclass this controller and create MySpecificController.h/.m/.xib

If I do this, however, MySpecificController.xib will be used.

How should I get the generic XIB and the specific XIB to work together?

Answer (score 0):

When even you are writing generic code it should be written in .h & .m or .mm files.

In your case, MyGenericController xib  UI layout will be not get inherited to specificController XIB